# Howto create a filter bar?

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, osx-lion

I would like to create a filter bar like the one in the Mail app:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on how I could do?

My application is targeted only at OS X 10.7+, so I'd really like to use the most modern method available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MGScopeBar](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/10/28/mgscopebar) is an open source component that will mostly do what you want. The appearance is not exactly the same, but you could easily change that.

Answer (score 2):

That is called `FavoritesBarView` in the Mail application. it looks like its source code exists in webkit source code.