# Mail-like Favorites Bar as seen in OS X Lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I'm interested in implementing a "Favorites Bar" in my Cocoa application in the same way that Apple have done so in the new version of Mail in Lion. I thought I had read that this was a standard control now, but I can't find any indication of this.

I've recently seen a similar control appear in the Evernote client when they claimed "Lion-ification of Evernote" which caused me to wonder was there a standard control out there.

So can anyone point me to docs for such a standard control, or can anyone recommend other implementations out there for replicating this functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto create a filter bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221427/howto-create-a-filter-bar)

Comment: Yes, I see this now - while searching I did not use the term "filter bar" as the terminology used by Apple themselves is "favorites bar" within Mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at MGScopeBar by Matt Gemmell: http://mattgemmell.com/source

Comment: Thanks Christian, in the absence of a built-in control this does seem like a very good alternative. Judging by the other post, I'm going to assume that there is no built-in and accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I should've mentioned that there is no builtin alternative.

Comment: I just noticed [AMButtonBar](http://www.harmless.de/cocoa-code.php) by Andreas Mayer. I haven't tried either of these out yet, but will do so soon.